# Including image as datalabels in packedbubble chart highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Trying to include an image in the datalabel of a packedbubble chart. The image is inserted into the datalabel but it wont align in the center. Sometimes it does and sometimes it does not. My approch is as :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css"/>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<div id="container1" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin-right: 0 " 
align="right"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/lang.js'%}"></script>
<script>
var screen_name={{screen_name|safe}}
var id={{id|safe}}
var chart1=Highcharts.chart('container1', {
    chart: {
        type: 'packedbubble',
        height:'100%'
    },
    title: {
        text: '<p data-mlr-text>أبرز 10 مغردین</p>',
        useHTML:true

    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

  tooltip: {
          useHTML:true,
          formatter:function(){
          var headerFormat=this.point.name;
          var pointFormat='<br /><b>'+this.point.y+'</b>'
          return [headerFormat,pointFormat]
                }

        },
            plotOptions: {
                packedbubble: {
                minSize: '40',
                maxSize: '80',
                zMin: 0,
                zMax: 5000,
                layoutAlgorithm: {
                   splitSeries: false,
                 gravitationalConstant: 0.02
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    align:'center',
                    enabled: true,
                useHTML:true,
                formatter: function(){
                width=this.point.marker.radius
                return '<img 
   src="https://avatars.io/twitter/'+this.point.name+'" style="max- 
   width:'+width+'px;max-height:'+width+'px"></img><br />'
                },
                 },
  style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    textOutline: 'none',
                    fontWeight: 'normal'
                }
            }
        },
   series: [{
        name: 'Top 10 Users',
        data: (screen_name),
    }]
});
```

As the size of the bubble is dynamic have included the max-height and width property of the image so that they stay inside of the bubble. But the image does not begin at the center of the circle. Its position changes everytime.
Want the image to completely fill the circle and does not go outside of the circle

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ta31suLk/. Could you use it as a template to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Yes, you can see that the image is not at the center of the bubble.

Comment: On my machine images are centered as expected. Which version of Highcharts are you using? Which system, browser? Perhaps try to set also dataLabels `align: 'center'` and `varticalAlign: 'middle'`. Another demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ghxkwqcu/

Comment: Well on the first try it never gets aligned to the center. Browser is chrome v77. I have to refresh the page in order to get them to the middle. Something weird is happening.

Comment: Maybe it has to do something with the fact that the chart is placed inside an iframe? or whether images are coming from another site.

Comment: http://34.66.198.6/5/screen_name/0/999999999999999/top/top/ this is an example you can see it

Comment: Ok, I can see it. Really strange behavior. Probably the only solution is to set explicitly the width and height of the image element `'<img src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png" width="30" height ="30">'`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yzrvu7eg/1/